# Перенаправление трафика VPN wireguard

Tags: маршрутизация, vpn, трафик, wireguard

Подскажите пожалуйста, вопрос связанный с маршрутизацией и VPN.
Какие распространенные практики связанные со следующей ситуацией: например есть сервер хост на котором настроен wireguard протокол. У клиента есть конфиг, в котором прописан ip хоста, с помощью которого он собственно и соединяется и трафик шифруется. Но вдруг появляется нужда в смене сервера-хостинга, соответственно и смене конфига у всех клиентов (т.к. сменился ip). Как построить систему что бы в случае смены хостинга не менять конфиги клиентов?
Я подозреваю что нужен дополнительный прокси сервер с nginx куда будет подключаться клиент, правильно ли это? Или есть какие-то другие практики подобных случав?

Comment: Вместо ip использовать домен